# hide tags from view but keep what they are used for

Tags: c#, jquery, css, telerik

Am using a telerik editor and need to know if there is a way to strip/hide html tags but keep the use?

An example is this:

Here is a < b >**bold**< /b > text.

Here is a **bold** text.

I've looked at HtmlServices but can't seem to find anything that will let you use the editor itself but when you save it, it only shows the text with the values attached minus the tags.

Comment: I must have miss something. You must see the tag in Html/Source Mode. And see the **bold** only in design mode. Or you want to be able to escape the tag so you can display `<b>` in your text?

Comment: Yeah so I have it in a Kendo grid, is there a way to hide the tags on screen to the user but keep the style attached

Comment: Yeah I guess escape them but keep them working

Comment: I can't find any reference of a Html/Source mode in Editor Api. So i guess you will have to let it in design mode where you can't write html. but you can set text too bold using the toolbar

Comment: OK well thanks for looking

Comment: I'm not a Kendo expert. but here is a sample that seems to do what you need. http://dojo.telerik.com/UJujA